# Can't complete mvn verify without jersey-container-servle-core

Tags: java, maven, jersey-2.0, servlet-3.0

I am trying to run mvn verify on my project with 2.22.1 Jersey version.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

When running mvn verify it says I am using  jersey-container-servle-core and I haven't declared it. According to Jersey notification this dependency in already in  jersey-container-servlet. Any idea?

Comment: scope running? did you mean scope runtime?

Comment: Assuming the above comment if a typo, could you post your POM, full stacktrace and the Maven command you used?

Comment: yep, it was a typo, I posted the actual problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used the "core" dependency in unit test and in web.xml.
In order to solve it I can do either:

1. Change continar-servlet to compile and then I will have it for test as well. Because container-servlet include "core", it will work on test as well.
2. Add jersey-container-servle-core just for test scope or with runtime